# How to show or read only form from website in webview? - swift

Tags: javascript, xcode, swift, uiwebview

Can any expert tell me how only show the login form this website in my `UIWebView` ?

http://webgiz.faqserv.com/webgiz/

(This is a screenshot in case my link will unavailable):

[image]

If I can not , how can I fill this form with my variables using Swift ?

For now I'm using as palliative code below : `WV1.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.getElementById('username')‌​.value = '" + RA + "'") WV1.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.getElementById('passwd').v‌​alue = '" + CPF + "'") WV1.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.getElementById('btnlogin')‌​.click()")`

Comment: If you need help you should insert some code about your custom UIWebView..

Comment: All right , thanks. How do I enter text (var) in textfields this webpage ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must detect the rest full parameters to login to this joomla portal:

for example:

**POST** method:
http://webgiz.faqserv.com/webgiz/index.php?option=com_aixgen&username=test&password=test&userType=A&instituicao=0

```
@IBOutlet weak var usernameTextField: UITextField!
// `passwordTextField.secureTextEntry = true`
@IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

...

@IBAction func signIn(sender: AnyObject) {
    var url = NSURL(string: "http://webgiz.faqserv.com/webgiz/index.php")
    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    // Get the user's credentials from the `UITextField`s
    var username: String = usernameTextField.text
    var password: String = passwordTextField.text

    // Concatenating everything together
    var userCredentials: String = "username=\(username)&passwd=\(password)&userType=A&instituicao=0" // add all parameters needed
    var bodyData: String = "\(userCredentials)"

    // Encode the bodyData string into a 
    request.HTTPBody = bodyData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    // load the UIWebView `webView` with this request
    webView.loadRequest(request)
}
```

Comment: Thank you again ! I'll try to find out the parameters . I'm doing a hobby . For now I'm using as palliative code below :
`WV1.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.getElementById('username').value = '" + RA + "'");`
            `WV1.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.getElementById('passwd').value = '" + CPF + "'");`
            `WV1.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.getElementById('btnlogin').click()");`

Comment: The method you have choice to approach could make no sense. If a user insert username and password correctly the webview redirect immediatly the url address to the site internal page. It's a passive listening method. The best thing to do in this case it's to intercept the webview login button "Entrar" when it's pressed and choose what to do..